# Neural Networks :: Classification without knowing total number of classes

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

If you've ever used Google Photos, you would've noticed that over time, it tags faces of unknown people and then prompts you to tag their names. But in doing so, it doesn't ask you tag all instances of person `X`'s faces in every single photo. Because it has already grouped all faces of each unknown person it has encountered in the photos.

From an ML perspective, I'm intrigued by how this happens. As far as I known (given my limited knowledge in the field despite my immense interest), a typical classification ML model requires you to train using known classes. And its output is ALWAYS going to be one of those classes and nothing else.

Google Photos can't possibly train on the face of every person in the world, but still needs to classify different faces of each person in your photos. Meaning the classes are not known during the training phase. How is it then able to classify faces of a single person unknown to it at training time?

Is there a type of Neural Net that's perfect for this kind of problem? I ask this cuz as part of my job, I'm dealing with a problem where I have to classify types of photos too, where the entire set of classes/labels isn't known at training time. As a rough example, consider a model that classifies handwritten numbers not just in the range of 0 to 9, but 0 to 299,792,458 and beyond. We can't possibly train on all handwritten images of numbers from 0 to infinity. But we'd like the model to correctly classify that an image with text `42` is different from one with text `43` or `4012` or `3.141592653589`.

So we ended up using a `TripletNet` network that requires an anchor, a positive sample and a negative sample. This allows the model to compute **similarity** between different images.

This works fine but requires that the algorithm save every image it encounters so that it can compare new images against for similarity. This has a couple of **MAJOR** disadvantages:

1. If there is no match, we save the image and associate a random unique ID to it. The next time a similar image is sent, we compute similarity and reuse the ID of the most similar image stored.
2. If we clear the database of images/unique IDs, the next time we get the same image, we'll compute a new unique ID which will be different from the one we got before the database was cleared. Ideally we'd like to get the same ID as before but that's not possible in this implementation.
3. We need to compare similarity against all stored classes and their images. This means the number of comparisons needed is directly proportional to the size of the store. Ideally we'd like to have a constant time lookup.
4. Suppose `A` is similar to `B` and `B` is similar to `C`, but `A` is not similar to `C`. In this scenario, if we classify `A`, then `B` then `C`, we'd end up with the same class for all three. However, if we classify `A` and then `C`, we'd end up with two separate classes. Meaning, the classification is heavily dependent on the order of earlier inputs to the system.

Although the company is content with what it has working at the moment, I believe there could be other types of Neural Networks that might be better suited for this task than what we have right now. Perhaps the answer to "How does Google Photos classify all faces of each unknown person" be also an answer to how we can improve our ML model to circumvent the issues noted in bullet points above. :)

Comment: It look impossible. Triplet loss indeeed is a good candidate but it is never used alone. Normally, it is used with SVM.  Google does not train the network fully but there is a feature extraction part and then some number of neurons are added for each account for classification task.

Comment: Thank you! Could you elaborate upon the last sentence a bit more?

Comment: For example: You can use an encoder-decoder approach. Use triplet loss at the end of the encoder to move similar data points to same output space. Once your encoder  is trained then decouple it's laster layer(which is triplet loss) and attach a new neuron(but you have know in advance how many categories you want) then train this newly added neuron without encoder-part